# Pagination data

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination

I'm trying to learn how to create pagination from [DevelopPHP](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Pagination-MySQLi-Google-Style-Paged-Results-Tutorial), but in their tutorial they didn't teach how I can create the data for the $list, meaning how I can echo $firstname, $lastname and $datemade? I tried

```
<?php
echo $firstname = "Name";
echo $lastname = "Lastname";
echo $datemade = "06 Oct 2016";
echo $list;
?>
```

but it doesnt show the other texts in list, such as "Click the link to view this testimonial" or "Written".

It should be like this:

[image]

But mine shows up like this:

[image]

Also what for stands `$id = $row["id"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study their code more, dont just copy&paste. You told the program to `echo` those variables and it echoed them for you. In the tutorial they seem to store all the 'paginatable' data in the $list, so you need to look into that. `$id = $row["id"];` prints `id` column from the current table in mySql

Edit: I will try to explain what most of the lines in the website you provided do.
I do not know if you are familiar with SQL, but you need to know basics of mysql to be able to create your pagination script.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

$sql prepares the sql statement that will count entries in the mysql table testimonials whose approved column is set to 1. Then $query uses the mysqli_query to process the sql statement ($db_con is declared in mysqli_connection.php, it tells the server how to connect to the database). [Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

$row is an array and here it only consists of 1 element - the number of entries in testimonials with approved=1. Therefore $rows is declared and it is set to that number -- $row[0].

```
$page_rows = 10;
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
```

`ceil` is a php function that rounds a number up to the closest integer (0.4 -> 1, 5.1 -> 6). $page_rows tells how many testimonials you want to be displayed per page, so $last takes total number of testimonials and divides them by 10 and the result is the number of pages. [Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_ceil.asp)

I will skip the next few lines of their code because they are very straightforward.

```
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
```

$_GET is a superglobal that collects data from the URL. If you have 18 testimonials, if you go to page 2, the url will take the form of "your_website/?pn=2". So here $pagenum is set to the value of the superglobal `pn` only if it is set (because by default, when you are on page 1 `pn` is not set) [Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

This is also an SQL statement that tells the server that the number of testimonials to be shown should be limited to 10 [Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, datemade FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

These two are once again mysql statements that select the columns `id, firstname, lastname, datemade` from your table with approved=1 and order all of the entries by their id in reverse order [Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Now I am pretty sure after you study all of the above, you will be able to figure out what the next lines do (their comments should help as well).

Important part is here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
    $datemade = $row["datemade"];
    $datemade = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($datemade));
    $list .= '<p><a href="testimonial.php?id='.$id.'">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' Testimonial</a> - Click the link to view this testimonial<br>Written '.$datemade.'</p>';
}
```

while statement is essential to know in PHP. It basically keeps executing the code in `{ code }` while the condition in `while (condition)` is true. Important to note that $row is an array (type `var_dump($row)` to see what $row contains). $row here should contain your mysql table entry values. So if your mysql table has a column called post_content, you can output its value using $row["post_content"].

mysqli_close closes the connection to the database.

If there is anything you dont understand let me know

Comment: FYI: I didn't copy&paste the code, I watched the total video and tried to learn. But didn't understand how i can put the data, because I'm newbie in PHP.

Comment: @RedRose ok sorry for assuming. From what i can see, you create a table in the mysql database, and connect to it. That's where the $list will be taking its data from

Comment: no problem..but could you please provide some example of it? Because I just learned php include and some other stuff, but pagination is very new for me, and I don't understand without an example

Comment: i will update the answer, have you studied mysql yet?

Comment: btw there are lots of tutorials on the web that use mysql_ instead of mysqli_. mysql was deprecated in PHP v5.5. Mysqli has a slightly different syntax to mysql, be aware of this

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything...but what I put into the body, because my main problem was that I don't know what kind of code to put in body, so it will show e.g. several post in order, where each of them have different names, lastnames, and dates?

Comment: $list contains the html code for your output. If you want to change the output, change the $list variable contents (it is inside the while loop). You dont need to change anything in body

Comment: or let me know what you want to do explicitly, i will guide you

Comment: If its not too much to ask, could you please provide an example of it too? I will really appreciate it. An example where you list posts, with different details and links to them

Comment: you have created a table in phpmyadmin (or any equivalent mysql tool) right? and have you inserted any data into this table?

Comment: and i cant watch their video, i m at work now, so i dont know what they do in the video that isnt descibed in their written tutorial

Comment: no, i don't know even how to do that...is there any example of it online, because I tried to find about how to make and insert the data to pagination, but didn't find anything

Comment: proceed to this link http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/php+mysql?password= type in any name and press chat